Renaming [rpgmakermv] to [rpg-maker]
RPG Maker is a series of programs for creating role-playing video games. The oldest versions have their own GUI-based programming languages. RPG Maker XP and VX, released in the late 2000s, support extensions coded in Ruby. The latest versions, RPG Maker MV and MZ, use JavaScript for the same purpose.
Currently, rpgmakermv does house mostly questions about RPG Maker MV. But some are about other versions of RPG Maker, probably because there is no rpg-maker. (Most are also a bit low-quality, but questions about programming in RPG Maker seem perfectly on-topic.)
Should we rename rpgmakermv to rpg-maker, and let combinations like "rpg-maker ruby" handle the various installments of the software and their different scripting languages?

I legitimately have no idea what the authors of such software were thinking with that versioning scheme. - Actually, I guess they must have taken inspiration from Microsoft and Adobe....

@KarlKnechtel because it's not a versioning scheme. It's a product differentiation one. There are as many similarities between XP and MV, as there are similarities between Java and Python. They serve a purpose as general language and as a low entry game "engines".

The rpgmakermv tag is already extremely small - enough that generally we'd be okay with someone retagging them unilaterally. I also can't see any other related tags - not only is there no rpg-maker, but no rpgmakermz etc. And it really looks to me like the tag isn't adding any value. I just removed it from this question, for example, where I genuinely can't see how it had anything to do with any RPG-making software at all.
A tag like this generally isn't going to help people understand the problem: the fact that the code is being written for use in the context of such software, isn't going to change the answer to the question, or impose additional constraints. On the rare occasion where it does matter, you're probably looking at a question that really should be on gamedev.SE instead.
I would recommend just removing this tag.

Why doesn't it add value to RPG Maker-specific questions, such as this question?
